# Configuring Apache Client timeout in apache module

Tags: apache2, apache-modules

I am writing an apache module and I am wondering how to handle the case where my ap_rwrite tries to write something back to the client and the client does not respond to it.
Does the call to ap_rwrite block until that happens?

Can I set a timeout on that? If so, what is it called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client does not respond to server again. HTTP is a request-response protocol, the client send a request to the server and server sends a response to client. Client should not respond to server.

If you mean how to know if the client receives the response maybe you can alter the default timeout, but if the socket is closed or other network error, the function 'ap_rwrite' will notice you with an error.